# Is it ethically correct for a physician to refuse a course of treatment demanded by the patient?

Tags: logic, kant, argumentation

I'm writing about the medical ethical dilemma of whether or not to give life-sustaining therapy if it is judged to be futile by the doctor anyhow.

I'm to write a logically valid argument FOR or AGAINST this premise (should a doctor give life-sustaining therapy if a patient wishes, but if the doctor deems it futile) using Kantian ethics.

Is this a valid argument for the premise?

*If a patient wishes to continue treatment, regardless of the doctor's opinion, it is ethically correct, according to the second formulation of Kantian ethics, to respect this wish, as the doctor would only be viewing the patient as means, instead of an end, if he denied him the treatment.*

Comment: Is there any chance you could make the headline more specific?

Comment: Please do feel free to improve further. Also it might be advisable here to try to ground this in some particular text or passage of Kant that you're studying.

Comment: I've included the second formulation of Kantian ethics as a grounding point.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see it? --It would help a lot here to work explicitly from the text -- explaining why you think a particular passage or line of reasoning supports your position

Comment: "it is ethically correct, according to the second formulation of Kantian ethics" In my argument.

I just need to know whether or not my argument is valid. I'm not supposed to argue for my argument, I'm supposed to bring a valid argument that is grounded in Kantian ethics about my dilemma. Therefore the short question.

Comment: How could it be "valid" without being related to the ethical arguments Kant gives? --What exactly are you looking for in an answer here?

Comment: I am relating it to the ethical argument that Kant gives. His second formulation. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I am asking you to indicate what *specifically* you are asking someone here to explain to you. If you aren't interested in the ethical arguments Kant actually gives, what are you hoping for someone to explain to you about your "position"?

Comment: I can read his arguments on wikipedia. I am to provide a VALID argument for my dilemma for my (short) paper in medical school. I want someone to tell me if this is a valid argument or not. If you were my instructor, would you see the argument as sufficient, because I'm not sure and my instructors are on vacation.

Comment: I have added the second formulation of Kant in my paper. Is it a valid argument then?

Comment: It seems to depend on all kinds of other information that you haven't specified. Why does the doctor refuse? Maybe he has only enough medication for one patient and there are two who need treatment. Maybe the treatment is prohibitively expensive. Maybe the administration of the treatment would cause other problems. If the doctor is refusing merely on a whim that would seem unethical, but it is hardly a likely scenario.

Comment: @Bumble  He is still in principle either right or wrong to do so, even if other contingent duties might override this one, it has an abstract status as either being a duty he might not be able to fulfill, or not being a duty at all.  Kant is not a situationalist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

There is no evidence the doctor is using the patient as a means to anything by doing nothing to him.

In fact, if he is providing care that he does not consider to ultimately help the patient in a real way, and he does not at least consider whether this is ultimately harmful, the doctor would be using the patient as a mere means.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried again with virtue ethics instead: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/31217/is-this-argument-with-roots-in-virtue-ethics-valid